# Best practice: Upload a picture for non existing Task

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am programming a CRM (Customer Relationship Management) where employees can add tasks and asign them to other employees (in PHP).

It's also required that the employees should be able to upload images for a task (e.g. When having a bug, they make print screens and add them to the task)

Now my question is, how would you make the association between the images and the task in the database? At the point where the employees enter the "create task form" in the GUI there will be no "task" entry in the database yet, therefore i can't assign the uploaded pictures to a "task_id". So my logic currently requires that the "task" entry in the DB is made, before you can upload a picture. Why? => Because when you have an entry for the table "task" you have the "task_id" which is required to make the entry in the "task_image" (for the foreign key).

I already thought about the option to create the task_id via GUID instead of using the auto increment function, but this is not possible due to other requirements.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem in respect of the auto-increment feature.

Answer (score 1):

If it's really not possible to make it so that the task is entered into the task table before you store the picture's details in the pictures table, you could simply use an arbitrary value for the taskID and pass it through forms using hidden fields, until you store the task in the table, then simply run an update query changing the taskID to the correct value instead of the arbitrary one at the end.

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO pictures (picID, taskID, ...) VALUES (NULL, 'arbitrary', ...);
//perform remaining operations related to task
//insert task into task table
UPDATE pictures SET taskID = $correcttaskid WHERE taskID = 'arbitrary';
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give specific advice without knowing how your code is structured but I understand you want to accept file uploads through a separate channel (e.g. some JavaScript code) way before task form is submitted, like Gmail does.

You can store files in a temporary directory outside web root with a long random name that's difficult to guess:

```
/home/foo/site/files/pending/5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="file" value="5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8">
```

... and add such name to a hidden form field. Later, when you've created the task and have your task ID, you can read the corresponding file and move it to its definitive location. To take into account:

- Never handle the original raw ID as path, e.g.:

  ```
  file_get_contents($_POST['file']);
  ```
- Design a process to make unused files expire (i.e., get deleted) after a given time

If you're particularly worried about security you can separate files from different users, either having a per-user directory or adding a prefix to file names:

```
/home/foo/site/files/pending/1234-5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="file" value="5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8">
```

```php
if (preg_match('/^[a-f0-9]+$/', $_POST['file'])) {
    $file = sprintf('/home/foo/site/files/pending/%d-%s', $_SESSION['user_id'], $_POST['file']);
}
```

Comment: you understood the problem correctly! What if i have to upload more than 1 pictures? what where the input names? like file-1 file-2 etc.? and how would i access them in PHP?

Comment: Please check [How do I create arrays in a HTML form?](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options. "Best practice" is a very subjective term, and it all depends on the context here.

The first option is that you create the "task" entry at the time the user uploads the image, and pass that back as a parameter to your main "task" form when the upload completes. You can store it in the current session, for instance; then when you complete the "task" entry, you check the session to see if there is a "taskID" set, and update that task ID, rather than create one.

```
<pseudo_code>
taskID = imageUpload (image)
session.store("taskID", taskID)
....
taskbutton.submitButton
  if (session.taskID)
    updateTask(taskID, formFields.name, formfields.description, ...)
  else
    createTask(formFields.name, formfields.description,....)
  end if
end

</pseudo_code>
```

This requires a bit of JavaScript in your form, but is nice and simple; the downside is that you may end up with incomplete tasks in your database (e.g. if the user abandons the form).

Another alternative is that you upload the image, but don't populate the foreign key until you know the taskID. This is harder than it may seem - you have to carry all the imageIDs in the session, so you can update them when you create the task. If the session times out, or if the user abandons the form, you end up with orphaned images.